# PowerShell doesn't return an empty array as an array

Tags: arrays, powershell

Given that this works:

```
$ar = @()
$ar -is [Array]
  True
```

Why doesn't this work?

```
function test {
    $arr = @()
    return $arr
}

$ar = test
$ar -is [Array]
  False
```

That is, why isn't an empty array returned from the test function?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Your function doesn't work because PowerShell returns all [non-captured stream output](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/09/16/effective-powershell-item-7-understanding-output/), not just the argument of the `return` statement. An empty array is mangled into `$null` in the process. However, you can preserve an array on return by [prepending it with the array construction operator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/01/23/array-literals-in-powershell.aspx) (`,`):

```
function test {
  $arr = @()
  return ,$arr
}
```

Comment: soooooo frustrating. If you return @(/*some filtered expression that has zero elements*/) you also encounter the same behaviour. return ,@(/*expr*/) is a fix... but it's hacky as hell. So easy to overlook.

Comment: This stupid workings cost me about a day in freaking time. I could not figure out how my script was double the values in the array. Thank you for posting that. Why would they even think that was a good idea for functions! So frustrating! The worst part is, I had an `$arr.add(1)` which was outputting the count of the array after. Doing `$x = $arr.add(1)` fixed the issue. Hacky.

Comment: @BradFJacobs: You could also use `... | Out-Null` or `... >$null` to suppress undesired output. I wouldn't consider returning all non-captured output a bad idea per se, though, it's just unexpected for most people with a background in other programming languages. When used properly it can actually simplify returning data from a function, because you don't have to collect all desired output in a variable before returning it.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers I am sure it makes sense when you figure out the proper usage and the reasoning by it. That is how all of powershell has been for me, once I learned why / the proper way to utilize it, it makes sense.

Comment: @BradFJacobs, while this is normally true, I think _return_ was just a mistake.  According to Bruce Payette (one of PowerShell's designers) the _return_ statement was added for _control flow_, and `return $x` is just shorthand for `Write-Output $x; return`.  Clearly the keyword should be **ExitSub** and it shouldn't accept an argument.

Comment: For ****sake! Thank you!

Comment: this returns an array with 1 element which is an empty array, not what OP asked for at all

`$sampleArray = , @()`
`$sampleArray.Length`

prints 1


`$sampleArray[0].GetType()`

`IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType`
`-------- -------- ----                                     --------`
`True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array`

Comment: Actually it behaves differently if returned from a function vs locally, locally it does create an array of size 1 containing an empty array, but when returned from a function PS seems to be unwrapping the outer layer and giving an empty array

Comment: @taras.roshko PowerShell unrolls enumerable collections on return.

Comment: Holy cow. So much time wasted before I stumbled upon this little nugget. Thank you.

Comment: It 'unrolls' enumerables? Why? Why on earth would anyone think it's a good idea to have a function that says it returns an array, but like.. only if there are > 1 elements, and a string if only 1 elements, and null if zero elements. Why not just return the thing it says to return like the code literally tells it to return.  The 'hack' doesn't even make sense, because it's literally already an array we're returning. How does adding a ',' to an array cause it to keep the already-an-array?

Answer (score 3):

`write-output $arr` is as afaik the same as just writing `$arr`.
So the function will still return `$null`.

**But** `write-output` has the option `-NoEnumerate`.
That means the empty Array will not be enumerated
(and therefore ignored - because it's empty). The result is an empty array.

admittedly the above answer is much shorter, ...

```
 function test {
     $arr = @()
     write-output $arr -NoEnumerate 
 }
 (test) -is [array]  ## $True
```

Comment: Late to the party but it's important to note that this only works if you do not pipe the input to ```Write-Output```. So ```Write-Output @() -NoEnumerate``` works as expected but ```@() | Write-Output -NoEnumerate``` does not. I hate PowerShell sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Another thing to keep in mind with the "prepend ','" solution, is that if you intend to serialize the data afterwards, you're going to run into some issues. What `,` appears to actually do is wrap whatever variable it's prepending into an array. so `$null` becomes `[]`, `"test"` becomes `["test"]`, but...... `["foo","bar"]` becomes `[["foo","bar"]]`, which is obviously an issue from a serialization standpoint.

Comment: If I understand correctly, wrapping in an array is exactly what's desired in this use case, because PowerShell natively unwraps it as part of the processing it does when returning from a function, and so the result is that the caller receives the object after the `,` in its unaltered form.  The examples you cited are what happens to the value *after* the `,` operator, but *prior* to being returned.