# Why can I call GetType() on an empty array but not when its returned from a function

Tags: powershell

In my never-ending quest to understand Powershell better can someone please explain this behaviour to me:

```
function fn1{return @()}
(@()).GetType()           #does not throw an error
(fn1).GetType()           #throws error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."
```

Why does returning a value from a function make it "different"?

Interestingly (or perhaps not), piping to get-member exhibits the same behaviour in both cases:

```
function fn1{return @()}
@()   | gm           #does throw an error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."
fn1   | gm           #does throw an error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."
```

Colour me confused. Can someone explain this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PowerShell doesn't return an empty array as an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476634/powershell-doesnt-return-an-empty-array-as-an-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because when you return an array (and probably any other collection) from function, PowerShell will put each element of array into a pipeline. So `GetType()` is actually not being called on empty array, but it's elements (that are missing).

The soulution could be to return your array in another array :).

```
function fn1{return ,@()}
(fn1).GetType()
```

Now Powershell will pass into a pipeline elements of this "parent" array, which happens to containt only one element: your empty array.
Please note that you can't achieve that by `return @(@())`, because external `@()` only assures that result returned will be an array, which it already is.

Comment: Still not sure I totally understand the reasoning but your proposed solution works. Thanks very much Adam.