# PowerShell function won't return empty array ever

Tags: arrays, powershell

I want a function to always return an array, even if it's empty `@()`. I've noticed that just coercing the output of a function with `@(MyFunction)` will return an array with 1 element (`$null`) if the function returns `$null`. What I want is to coerce the result to empty array `@()` instead.

So how can we return an empty array from a function in PowerShell?

```bsh
function ReturnAnEmptyArray() {return @()}
function ReturnNull() {return $null}

$a = @()
Write-Host "`$a is an empty array of length $($a.length) and type $($a.gettype())"
$b = ReturnAnEmptyArray
Write-Host "`$b is null: $($b -eq $null) but should be an empty array @()"
$c = @(ReturnNull)
Write-Host "`$c is an array of length $($c.length) and type $($c.gettype()) and `$c[0] is null $($c[0] -eq $null)"
$d = [array](ReturnNull)
Write-Host "`$d is just plain `$null $($d -eq $null) and not an array"
```

Output:

```
$a is an empty array of length 0 and type System.Object[]
$b is null: True but should be an empty array @()
$c is an array of length 1 and type System.Object[] and $c[0] is null True
$d is just plain $null True and not an array
```

Is there any sure way to have a function return an empty array??

```bsh
function ConvertTo-Array($Obj) {
    # Return array as array
    if ($Obj -is [array]) {return $Obj}
    # Return $null as empty array @() => Fails to deliver @()
    elseif ($Obj -eq $null) {return @()}
    # Other values/objects (e.g. strings) are wrapped in an array
    else {return @($Obj)}
}
```

Comment: This might lead give you a direction: [PS Doesn't return Empty Array as an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476634/powershell-doesnt-return-an-empty-array-as-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the same answer from Ansgar should help you in returning but its not a good way to deal

```
function returnemptyarray {
  $arr = @()
  return ,$arr
}

$a = returnemptyarray 
$a.gettype()
```