# Add-Member ScriptProperty deduce empty array or single item array to no array item

Tags: powershell

```
$obj = New-Object -Type PSObject
$obj | Add-Member -Type ScriptProperty -Name ArrayMember {"" -split ","}
$obj.ArrayMember.GetType().Name
```

Output: String

```
$obj = New-Object -Type PSObject
$obj | Add-Member -Type ScriptProperty -Name ArrayMember {"1" -split ","}
$obj.ArrayMember.TetType().Name
```

Output: String

```
$obj = New-Object -Type PSObject
$obj | Add-Member -Type ScriptProperty -Name ArrayMember  {"1,2" -split ","}
$obj.ArrayMember.GetType().Name
```

Output: Object[]

I want to directly use `$obj.ArrayMember += 3` to append 3 into the array, but if it return a string, like "1", the result will be 13, but I expected [1,3].

Comment: similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476634/powershell-doesnt-return-an-empty-array-as-an-array

Comment: `,("" -split ",")`, `,("1" -split ",")`, `,("1,2" -split ",")`. Note that it first case you have single element array, but not empty array.

Comment: declare your object property as an array _first_. that way the property is defined as an array. something like this ... >>> `$TestObject = [PSCustomObject]@{ArrayPropOne = [array]@()}` <<< however, you may want to define it as a `generic.list` since that has a working `.Add()` method. [*grin*]