# Why does an array with a single empty array have the length of 0?

Tags: arrays, powershell

The `Length` property works as expected on all arrays that I test except one weird case:

```
PS> @(@()).Length
0
```

It's not that empty arrays are generally omitted though:

```
PS> @(@(), @()).Length
2

PS> @(@(), @(), @()).Length
3
```

What's going on?

Comment: In the 1st case, PowerShell unrolls the inner array, which is empty. Thus, the outer array becomes empty too. This is just how the array sub-expression operator `@()` works. Another example to confirm: `@(@(1,2,3)).Length` outputs `3` instead of `1`.

Comment: Following on @zett42's comment, this is why using the unary form of the comma operator, you get your expected results: `@(,@()).Count`

Comment: The keyword here is "array unrolling". This is a source of a lot of question and there is a lot on SO and elsewhere on the topic and all the gotchas. As a simple rule of me, generically speaking, always wrap results of function that return a collection in an array (eg: `$Stuff = @(Get-Collection)` so that you get an array no matter what. If you don't do that, then empty collections get unrolled into `$null`, single item collections get unrolled in their single element type and collection with more elements get automatically unrolled in the outer collection, making all ths a bit more consistent

Comment: See; [PowerShell doesn't return an empty array as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18477004/1701026)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **`@(...)`**, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) is ***not* an array *constructor*, it is an array "guarantor"** (see next section), and ***nesting* `@(...)` operations is *pointless***.

  - `@(@())` is in effect the same as `@()`, i.e. an empty array of type `[object[]]`.
- **To *unconditionally* construct arrays, use `,`**, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-).

  - To construct an array wrapper for a *single* object, use the *unary* form of `,`, as [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) suggests:

    ```bash
    # Create a single-element array whose only element is an empty array.
    # Note: The outer enclosure in (...) is only needed in order to 
    #       access the array's .Count property.
    (, @()).Count # -> 1
    ```

<sup>Note that I've used `.Count` instead of `.Length` above, which is more PowerShell-idiomatic; `.Count` works across different collection types. Even though [`System.Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array) doesn't *directly* implement `.Count`, it does so via the `ICollection` interface, and PowerShell allows access to interface members without requiring a cast.</sup>

---

##### Background information:

- **`@(...)`'s *primary* purpose is to ensure that output objects collected from - invariably *pipeline*-based - *commands* (e.g, `@(Get-ChildItem *.txt)`) are *always* collected as an array** (invariably of type `[object[]]`) - even if `...` produces only *one* output object.

  - If getting an array is desired, use of `@(...)` is necessary because collecting output that happens to contain just *one* object would *by default* be collected *as-is*, i.e. *not* wrapped in an array (this also applies when you use `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--)); only for *multiple* output objects is an array used, which is always `[object[]]`-typed.
  - Note that PowerShell commands (typically) do *not* output *collections*; instead, they *stream* a (usually open-ended) number of objects *one by one* to the pipeline; *capturing* command output therefore requires *collecting* the streamed objects - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020105/45375) for more information.
- **`@(...)`'s *secondary* purpose is to facilitate defining array *literals*, e.g. `@('foo', 'bar')`**

  - Note:

    - Using `@(...)` for this purpose was *not* by original design, but such use became so prevalent that an optimization was implemented in version 5 of PowerShell so that, say, `1, 2` - which is sufficient to declare a 2-element array - may also be expressed as `@(1, 2)` without unnecessary processing overhead.
    - On the plus side, `@(...)` is visually distinctive in general and syntactically convenient specifically for declaring *empty* (`@()`) or *single-element* arrays (e.g. `@(42)`) - without `@(...)`, these would have to expressed as `[object[]]:new()` and `, 42`, respectively.
    - However, this **use of `@(...)` invites the misconception that it acts as an *unconditional* array constructor**, which isn't the case; in short: **wrapping extra `@(...)` operations around a `@(...)` operation does *not* create *nested* arrays, it is an *expensive no-op***; e.g.:

      ```bash
      @(42)    # Single-element array
      @(@(42)) # !! SAME - the outer @(...) has no effect.
      ```
  - **When `@(...)` is applied to a (non-array-literal) *expression***, what this expression evaluates to is *sent to the pipeline*, which **causes PowerShell to *enumerate* it**, if it considers it enumerable;<sup>[1]</sup> that is, if the expression result is a *collection*, its *elements* are sent to the pipeline, one by one, analogous to a command's streaming output, before being ***collected again* in an `[object[]]` array**.

    ```bash
    # @(...) causes the [int[]]-typed array to be *enumerated*,
    # and its elements are then *collected again*, in an [object[]] array.
    $intArray = [int[]] (1, 2)
    @($intArray).GetType().FullName # -> !! 'System.Object[]'
    ```

    - To *prevent* this enumeration and re-collecting:

      - Use the expression as-is and, if necessary, enclose it just in [`(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--)
      - To again ensure that an *array* is returned, an efficient alternative to `@(...)` is to use an `[array]` *cast*; the only caveat is that if the expression evaluates to `$null`, the result will be `$null` too (`$null -eq [array] $null`):

        ```bash
        # With an array as input, an [array] cast preserves it as-is.
        $intArray = [int[]] (1, 2)
        ([array] $intArray).GetType().FullName # -> 'System.Int32[]'

        # With a scalar as input, a single-element [object[]] array is created.
        ([array] 42).GetType().FullName # -> 'System.Object[]'
        ```

---

<sup>[1] See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530467/45375) for an overview of which .NET types PowerShell considers enumerable in the pipeline.</sup>

Comment: Okay, that not only answered my question, but also justified the logic behind. Would it be right to think that `@(1,2,3)` is actually an array `1,2,3` arrayified again with `@()`?

Comment: @radrow, historically speaking, yes - until v5 came along, which, loosely speaking, optimizes the `@(...)` away in this scenario (strictly speaking, `@(...)` is still parsed in this case, but special-cased to avoid re-creating the array). However, the  re-creation _does_ happen with non-literal operands; e.g: `$a = 1, 2; @($a)`