# Array of characters instead of array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, command-line, tostring

I am trying to get a list of SMB shares on a remote file server. Unfortunately because of the type of server I am querying WMI and CIM won't work. The only thing I can get to work is net view (which I believe uses netbios).

I am running the following code which gets the shares:

```
$shares = net view \\server1 /all | select -Skip 7 | ?{$_ -match 'disk*'} | %{$_ -match '^(.+?)\s+Disk*'|out-null;"\\server1\$($matches[1])"}
$shares += net view \\server2 /all | select -Skip 7 | ?{$_ -match 'disk*'} | %{$_ -match '^(.+?)\s+Disk*'|out-null;"\\server2\$($matches[1])"}


foreach ($share in $shares) {
    $logdir1 = @("$share\App_Data\","errorlogs")
    $logdirs = @($logdir1)

    foreach ($log in $logdirs) {
        write-host $log[0]
```

However, instead of getting a list of paths, I am getting the first character of each path. So basically $log[0] is a character - not a string as I an expecting.

I think this has to do with the net view command returning characters instead of an object.

I tried using `ToString()` in various places to no avail. Anyone help me figure out how to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: what does `$@(log)[0]` give you

Comment: Get-Log : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At C:\ErrorLogs.ps1:72 char:17
+         write-host $@(log)[0]
+                       ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Log], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.GetLog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

Your problem came down to the **misconception that `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) is an array *constructor*, which it is *not*: instead, think of it as an array *guarantor***.

Thus, replace:

```bash
$logdirs = @($logdir1) # WRONG: same as $logDirs = $logdir1 in this case.
```

with:

```bash
$logdirs = , $logdir1
```

... in order **to create a *nested* array** whose one and only element is the  two-element array contained in `$logDir`, using **`,` the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-)**, which you can then enumerate with `foreach` and refer to its elements with `[0]` and `[1]`.

For **background information on `@(...)`**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72718166/45375).

---

**Original answer:**

> ```bash
> $logdir1 = @("$share\App_Data\","errorlogs")
> $logdirs = @($logdir1)
> ```

... can be reduced to `$logdirs = @("$share\App_Data\", "errorlogs")`

> ```bash
>     foreach ($log in $logdirs) {
> ```

... then enumerates the elements of the array of string values in `$logDirs`

> ```bash
>     write-host $log[0]
> ```

... then refers to the *first character* (`[0]`) of the string value at hand (indexing into a *string* extracts the character at the specified position; e.g., `'abc'[1]` yields `'b'`)

Therefore, everything works as expected.

Perhaps you meant to *enumerate the files* inside the directory referenced by each `$log` value (renamed to `$logDir` for clarity below)?

```bash
foreach ($logdir in $logdirs) {
  $filesInDir = Get-ChildItem -File -LiteralPath $logdir
  $filesInDir[0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

External tools always return `string[]` with each line of output being an element in the output array.

You need to parse those lines for use with Powershell first, assuming of course "line of output" is sufficient (as in DIR /B output from cmd). The `-replace` operator might be of help there (NB: uses regex patterns rather than string matching).

It's probably a good idea to extract such interop code into its own function / module.